# How to to retrieve each node with nested children in family tree in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

[Here is the image of a family tree which I am creating dynamically. I have defined the first node which is Shan like below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzxDx.png)

```
var familyHead = {
  name: 'Shan',
  gender:'Male',
  grandfather:'null',
  grandmother:'null',
  father:'null',
  mother:'null',
  wife:{}
}
```

To complete the tree I have created methods as Add_wife, Add_husband, and Add_child which I am calling while adding and completing the tree given in the image starting from the above node point. Then I am retrieving the relationships (son, daughter, siblings, In-Laws, etc.) for given input any name.

But while adding the wife object at one level, I am facing an error as: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`

```
async function addWifeOperation(str){  //assigning and sending parameters to wifebject before addWife
    var husbandName = str[1]; //'Chit'
    var wifeName = str[2]; //'Amba'

    const display = async(person) => {

      if(person.name == husbandName) {
        var wife = {
          name:wifeName,
          husband:husbandName,
          fil:person.father,
          mil:person.mother,
          children : []
        }
        person.wife = wife;
      }

      if (person.wife.children && person.wife.children.length && typeof person.wife.children === "object") {
        console.log("person.wife = "+ JSON.stringify(person.wife));
        person.wife.children.forEach(display);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Or maybe any other way where I can dynamically create this tree using javascript and then retrieve the basis of the name on the relationship as input.

Answer (score 0):

`person.wife = wife;` may not be executed, so `person.wife` can be undefined.
It is better to check whether `person.wife` is undefined.

```js
if (person.wife) {
      if (person.wife.children && person.wife.children.length && typeof person.wife.children === "object") {
        console.log("person.wife = "+ JSON.stringify(person.wife));
        person.wife.children.forEach(display);
      }
}
```

Comment: person.wife is defined. I am not getting an error with that.

Comment: Your error message says that `person.wife` is `undefined`. Is your error occured in line `if (person.wife.children && person.wife.children.length && typeof person.wife.children === "object") {` ?

Comment: I am getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Comment: error is occuring in this line:         person.wife.children.forEach(display);